# Create page with unique incremental ID in confluence

Tags: confluence

I would like each page to have a unique ID but not the Confluence one.
So that at page creation automatically, the next number is picked. This has to work across spaces as it is a document count.

Is there a vanilla way to do it or if not, a plugin recommendation that does it would be fine.

Comment: When you create a page Confluence automatically picks a number which is called draft-number or id untill your page is saved. Once you save your page it disregards the page id and creates a pageId. I do not think that a plugin can do it or needs to do it. But, I am curious why would you like to do that, may be there's another way to solve your particular problem.

Comment: @MrKumar I cannot use that. I have historical data that needs importing and those numbers cannot chance.